# Node2D rotation not relative to parent

Tags: 2d, godot

Godot 3.2.2

Godot docs define [Node2D.rotation_degrees](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node2d.html#class-node2d-property-rotation-degrees) as "Rotation in degrees, relative to the node's parent."

Scene.gd:

```
extends Node2D

func _ready():
    var child = Node2D.new()
    add_child(child)
    child.set_position(Vector2(1, 1))
    child.rotation_degrees = 90
    print(child.get_position())
```

Play scene.
Output: `(1, 1)`
Expected: `(1, -1)`

If I override the child's _draw() method to make it display, I can see that its drawing context is rotating about its own origin.

But given the documentation, I would expect its position and drawing context to rotate about its parent's origin. This doesn't appear to be happening.

Is there something basic about the geometry that I'm misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `child.rotation_degrees = 90` means that whatever the parent's rotation, the child is rotated an *additional* 90 degrees.

As for what it's rotated around, that depends. If you rotate the parent, the child is rotated relative to the parent. If you rotate the child, it's rotated relative to itself, aka "locally".

By default, `Node2D.new()` is `centered` locally, so rotation causes it to spin in place. Calling `set_position` only changes its relation to the parent. If you want to change its local position you need to `translate` it.